# convergence and absolute convergence of infinite product

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

> Question: For what values of $p >0$ does the infinite product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p}$ converge? For what of $p >0$ does the infinite product converge absolutely.

**My attempt:** Note that if $a_n \geq0$ for all $n$ then
$$\prod_n (1-a_n)\ \text{converges} \iff \sum_n a_n\ \text{converges}$$
Writing $n^{-p} = 1 - (1 - n^{-p})$ where $a_n = 1 - n^{-p}$ is nonnegative for each $n\in \mathbb{N}, p > 0$ then as
$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} 1 - \frac{1}{n^p} = 1$, by divergence test, $\sum_n a_n = \sum_n (1 - n^{-p})$ does not converge.
So, there does not exists any such $p > 0$ in which $\prod_p \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges or converge absolutely.

Could I check if there are any gaps in my proof, as this was listed as an exam problem, yet my solution seems quite trivial.

Comment: On the other hand, $\frac1n^p<1,\forall n\in\Bbb N,p>0$ so, letting $x_n=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac1{n^p},$ you see $x_{n+1}=\frac1{(n+1)^p}x_n<x_n,\forall n\in\Bbb N, p>0$

Comment: @Invisible The infinite product is said to converge if there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ so that $\prod_n (1 - a_n) = \alpha$. 
As stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: Deleted the wrong part of my comment.

Comment: @Invisible For the comment at the top, are you trying to show directly that $\prod_n \frac{1}{n^p} =0$ for all $p >0$ so the infinite product does not converge?

Comment: Yes, consider $b_1=1,b_n=\frac1{2^p}.$ Then $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^\infty a_n\le\prod_{n=1}^\infty b_n$

Comment: @Invisible I see thank you!